# Make list-icon of my collapsed navigation show on tablet/phone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my website responsive with Twitter bootstrap, but I'm having some problems with my navigation. I'm using bootstrap's navigation menu but it won't change to a dropdown button on my tablet/phone. It's only showing when my iPad is portrait, but not when it's landscape.

I'm using these media queries:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */ 
@media (max-width: 767px) { }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { }
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="row">               
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"></a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li class="home active"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <div class="nav-separator hidden-desktop"></div>
                <li><a href="projecten">PROJECTEN</a></li>
                <div class="nav-separator hidden-desktop"></div>
                <li><a href="sketch">SKETCH</a></li>
                <div class="nav-separator hidden-desktop"></div>
                <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap of Twitter?

Comment: Yes, Twitter bootstrap

Comment: Please read the tag description. The tag 'bootstrap' is connected to a different topic.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: and portrait/landscape screenshots?